# Using MySQL (Embedded) in Nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, mysql, node-webkit

I am creating an App that uses almost the same code base. We are still in decision phase, and things can change. So far for the desktop we planned ot use Sqlite, and for the server version we planned to use MsSQL.

Ideally it would be great to use one DB for both sides. I just recently heard that MySQL has [embbeded](https://www.mysql.com/oem/) MySQl Db.

I have lots of problems with maintaining the Sqlite on my project, and I think using the MySQL would be ideal. I have few quesitons regarding this topic.

1. If I were to use MySQL embedded DB, do I have to compile it same as Sqlite?
2. Has anyone ever done it?

The desktop verison is going to be self contained, without need for internet connection. Thus, whatever embedded DB we choose, must be 100% embedded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, allow me to say I never used MySQL embedded DB. Back in the day when I searched for embedded MySQL, I couldn't find a free (the one you linked cost money) one, and even that from what I read was far from being easy to maintain.

I did number of projects that required a local DB. For most SQLite did the job like a champ. Only thing sometimes I had problem with building it.

Than, a friend told me about [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb):

> Embedded persistent or in memory database for Node.js, nw.js, Electron and browsers, 100% JavaScript, no binary dependency. API is a subset of MongoDB's and it's plenty fast.

If you need a embedded DB in node I recommend you to have a look at it.

Comment: Tha is very nice information. I will certanly take a look at the NeDB. No need to compile it for NW?

Comment: No, no build required. [install](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#user-content-installation-tests) from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nedb).